# How to display numbers less than 3 from an Array

Tags: java

I am supposed to write a program that accepts 6 user inputs and display numbers less than 3. I don't  know what the problem is and I can't find help anywhere.

```
public class Apples {

    public static void main(String [] args{
        double [] numList = new double [6];   

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in);
        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
            numList[i]=scan.nextDouble(); //user input
        }
        Arrays.sort(numList[i]);  //sort user input
        for (numList < 3)
           System.out.println(numList); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare your 2 `for` statements. Does the 2nd one look right?

Comment: You must have faced a compilation error at : Arrays.sort(numList [i]);  Even before fixing error you are here. Great !!

Comment: oh by the way, the closing bracket `)` is missing in the `main` method header

Comment: i did not see that,thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

I would to something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
            double number = scan.nextDouble();
            if(number < 3.0) {
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }
    }
```

So:

1. If it's just about printing, you don't need to store in an array the numbers, that you get from input.
2. You don't need sorting, you can just check if the number that you have currently scanned is smaller than 3 (or double 3.0).
3. The `for(numList < 3)` is not a correct Java syntax. You probably meant `if(number < 3)`

Comment: the assignment was under arrays so the user input was to be stored in an array which i named it "numList" and print out the inputs which are less than 3.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to copy/paste but there where quite some problems, let me show you one solution:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    double [] numList = new double [6];   

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in);
    // until here everything is fine

    for (int i = 0; i<numList.length; i++){    // just a hint: use the array's length. Maybe you want to change the array one day and add 20 numbers to it..
        numList[i]=scan.nextDouble(); // you forgot the . and it is called nextDouble()  (capital D)
    }
    Arrays.sort(numList);  // sorting is fine, just make sure you sort the whole array (not just one element)
    for (int i = 0; i<numList.length; i++){  // here I assume you want to print every element smaller than 3, so you still need to iterate over the whole array (maybe the user inputs only twos
        if(numList[i]<3){    // test if the number is smaller than 3
            System.out.println(numList[i]);    // and print it
        }
    }
}
```

if however you want to print only the 3 smallest elements of the array, then your approach was correct (though you still need to write out the whole `for` conditions:

```
for(int i=0; i<3;i++){
    System.out.println(numList[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last for doesn't work like that. With a for you can iterate trough numbers like you did in the first one or through lists/arrays.
I didn't understood if you wanted the smallest 3 or the ones smaller than 3.
If you want the smallest 3 you can do this:

```
double smallList[] = new double[3]
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
  smallList[i] = numList[i];
}
```

or if you want to print it one by one:

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
  System.out.println(numList[i]);
}
```

if you want the ones that are smaller than 3 you'll have to do:

```
for (int i=0;i<numList.length;i++) {
  if (numList[i]<3) {  
    System.out.println(numList[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: i did the correction and also change my last code to your last point and it worked perfectly. your tips was very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of printing them out.

```java
      double[] numList = new double[6];

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         numList[i] = scan.nextDouble(); // user input
      }
      // then do
      Arrays.stream(numList).filter(a -> a < 3).forEach(System.out::println);

      // or

      for (double n : numList) {
         if (n < 3) {
            System.out.println(n);
         }
      }
```